# How to launch Chrome app from android native app

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, chromebook

I want to know is there any way that I can launch chrome app (not chrome browser app) installed on Chromebook via the android app installed on the same device, the android app is apk.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
String urlString = "http://mysuperwebsite";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(urlString));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setPackage("com.android.chrome");
try {
  context.startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
// Chrome browser presumably not installed so allow user to choose instead
intent.setPackage(null);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

}

You specify what url you want to open and this code will check if chrome is available, if not it will let you choose what other browsers you can use.